# rmr zknode with ACL

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have created a new zknode with acl as follows.

```
[0]addauth digest username:password
[1]create /testnode mydata auth:username:password:crdwa,world:anyone:r
```

This successfully creates the zknode, and then I quit zkCli session.

Now, when I login into zkCli session again. If I donot do "addauth digest username:password" as my first command then I cannot read and write the /testnode, which is as expected. But I am able to run **rmr** and **delete** commands

```
[0]rmr /testnode -> this command deletes the zknode, which I do not want.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ACL you have defined on /testnode restricts access so that anyone can read the data in the znode, but only the authenticated user can create children under /testnode, delete children under /testnode, write data to the znode or administer the znode permissions.  This ACL does not place any restriction on deleting /testnode, because really that is an operation on the parent directory: deleting a child of /.

The Apache documentation on [ZooKeeper access control using ACLs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ZooKeeperAccessControl) describes the permission settings in more detail:

> ZooKeeper supports the following permissions:
>
> - **CREATE**: you can create a child node
> - **READ**: you can get data from a node and list its children.
> - **WRITE**: you can set data for a node
> - **DELETE**: you can delete a child node
> - **ADMIN**: you can set permissions

To restrict deletion of a child znode, you would need to apply an ACL on its parent, and that ACL would have to restrict DELETE access.